# Getting ImportError: dlopen , Symbol not found: when calling " import tensorflow_text as tf_text "

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the below :
tensorflow 2.12.0
tensorflow-text 2.12.0
numpy 1.23.5
Python version : 3.11

When executing the below line in Jupyter :
`import tensorflow_text as tf_text`

I get the below error :

---

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)

Cell In\[2\], line 1
\----\> 1 import tensorflow_text as tf_text

File \~/pythonenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow_text/__init__.py:20
17 from tensorflow.python.util.all_util import remove_undocumented
19 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
\---\> 20 from tensorflow_text.core.pybinds import tflite_registrar
21 from tensorflow_text.python import keras
22 from tensorflow_text.python import metrics

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/s0m0ifd/pythonenv/lib/python3.11/site-    packages/tensorflow_text/core/pybinds/tflite_registrar.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found:     (\__ZN4absl12lts_2022062320raw_logging_internal21internal_log_functionE)
Referenced from: '/Users/s0m0ifd/pythonenv/lib/python3.11/site-    packages/tensorflow_text/core/pybinds/tflite_registrar.so'
Expected in: '/Users/s0m0ifd/pythonenv/lib/python3.11/site-    packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib'
```

I have tried re-installing tensorflow and tensorflow-text , however that doesnt help.
Expecting to successfully import tensorflow-text

Answer (score 0):

**Tensorflow-text >2.10** has stopped supporting on some specific System OS which could be the reason of this error. Please refer to this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/text#a-note-about-different-operating-system-packages) where it is specified, that:

> After version 2.10, we will only be providing pip packages for **Linux
> x86_64 and Intel-based Macs**. 
> For other systems like **Windows, Aarch64, and Apple Macs**, TensorFlow relies on build collaborators, and so we will not be
> providing packages for them.